# Is it possible to know whether my platform is 64 or 32 bit using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm not sure about my platform,

can I diagnose it programatically?

Comment: Do you know what CPU you have? Or do you have commandline access?

Answer (score 4):

print out the max int value

```
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

output on 32bit hardware

```
2147483647
```

output on 64bit hardware

```
9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using PHP, `phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL)` should show your server's information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the OS (not the hardware) then you should be able to get this info from [php_uname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php).

If you want to know whether the hardware is 32 or 64-bit then on Linux you should be able to get this info from /proc/cpuinfo, on Windows you will have to use the Win32 API. Though it's quite possible that this will not work on shared hosting...

BTW You might want to check out the source code of [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/) to see how you can get hardware information.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably want to find it buried in one of the [predefined variables.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

Another good place to look would be the [Windows-only services.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php)